# Count always return 1 for non existent key

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying a select count query for a key which is not existing but i'm getting count value as 1. My query is `select count(*) from test_table where key = 'test'`.

But there is no key called test. But my query is always returning 1. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why is this tagged `C`?

Comment: Are you sure you read the row and don't simply read the row count (this query always returns **1** row) ? Can we see some code ?

Comment: why is this tagged `java` ?

Comment: Dixline please accept the answer by pressing V if it was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The single row is the value 0 for that count. In mysql it will return a single row such as:
    count(*) 0

Comment: No, this is an answer. Albeit a very simple and, **most especially, correct** one!